# What is the best way or tool to open to read a raw clickstream blob storage data in azure

Tags: api, azure-blob-storage, clickstream

I have clickstream blob storage about 800mb average file sizes and when i open the file it defaults to text file. How do i open and read the data possibly json format or column format. I would also like to understand if i can build an API to consume that data. I recently built an azure function app http trigger but the file is too large to open it up and the function times out. So any suggestion on those two would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What does “800MG” mean?

Comment: the file sizes are about average that big